# from directory import file

Tags: python, file, import, directory

I'm trying to import 'file.py' in another file (lets call it 'current.py') in Python3. Both the files are in same directory.

I tried all solutions listed in this link :[Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python) but am still unable to resolve the issue.

Also can someone please tell me what to do when the file I'm working on is in different directory from the one I want to use

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```
.
|_ file.py
|_ current.py
```

And you want to import the object `Foo` in `current.py`, just write at the beginning of `current.py`

```
import file
from file import Foo
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Here is an example

Well, you missed something then, I did this and it worked perfectly:

```
➜  tree
.
├── current.py
├── file.py
2 files
➜  python3 current.py
hello
```

here is `current.py`:

```
import file
from file import Object
a = Object()
```

and `file.py`:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')
```

Comment: I'm using Rodeo on Mac where it's not working.
When I use PyCharm its working successfully.
Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you like to import is called `my_file.py` just use:

```
import my_file as mf
```

If no error raises, the problem may be related to your code inside of a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

statement. If you are using this statement in your `my_file.py` this part won't be imported because you're not running your file from there. Only function, classes and other structures outside of this if statement will be imported.